# После подключения к ВПН пропадает интернет

Tags: linux, сеть

Имеется VPS с кали линукс (доступ по рдп). После установки прописал днс 8.8.8.8 Установил ВПН (без поддержки openvpn). После подключения к впн через несколько секунд выкидывает с впс. Не могу подключиться по рдп обратно к серверу. Подключается после перезагрузки сервера. Собственно как сделать так, чтобы трафик из впс в интернет шёл через впн, а подключение по рдп сохранялось

Comment: VPN изменяет шлюз по умолчанию (вернее, добавляет свой, но с меньшей метрикой - и он является приоритетным). Всё остальное - следствие. Измените настройки VPN, чтобы установление канала анонсировало только реально необходимые маршруты в строго определённые подсети, но не маршрут по умолчанию.

Comment: Я даже не могу зайти в настройки впна. Он сразу после запуска подключается и рдп обрывается.
https://postimg.cc/kV2Y2vNP - ip route

Comment: А зачем его запускать-то? для перенастройки это явно лишнее действие...

Comment: Имеется нужна, чтобы трафик ВПСки шел через ВПН, при этом я параллельно сидел через РДП. Проблема в том, что при подключении к ВПНу сразу пропадает РДП доступ

Comment: Надо прописать два маршрута? Один для того чтобы трафик шел через ВПН? А другой для РДП доступа? Но не знаю как их прописать...

Comment: Есть ли чёткое разделение по адресам узлов назначения (вот эти - только RDP, а остальные - только VPN.. либо наоборот)?

Comment: Нет, такого нету. Я пытаюсь этого добиться, но не знаю как это сделать. Не могли бы привести пример, пожалуйста?